# How to sort Json by date (newest to oldest)

Tags: json, sorting, date

i have a json feed with articles in it (and new coming every few days) and i need to get latest three out. The problem is, that json is not sorted by date and i don't know, how to rearrange it newest to oldest by date. I use js/jQuery. My json file looks like this:

```
[  
{  
  "author":"some text",
  "title":"some text",
  "description":"some text",
  "image_big":"image link",
  "image_small":"image link",
  "date":"2015-06-17",
  "content":"some text some text some text some text some text",
  "category":"category",
  "subcategory":[
     "some subcategory"
  ],
  "keywords":"keywords,keywords...",
  "id":"45654",
  "url":"article link"
},
.
. (more articles)
.
]
```

Comment: Do you use javascript to manage your json content?

Comment: Oh, sorry forgot to mention, i use js/jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.sort()` function. Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var data = [{
    "author": "some text",
    "title": "some text",
    "description": "some text",
    "image_big": "image link",
    "image_small": "image link",
    "date": "2015-06-17",
    "content": "some text some text some text some text some text",
    "category": "category",
    "subcategory": [
      "some subcategory"
    ],
    "keywords": "keywords,keywords...",
    "id": "45654",
    "url": "article link"
  }, {
    "author": "some text 2",
    "title": "some text 2",
    "description": "some text 2",
    "image_big": "image link 2",
    "image_small": "image link 2",
    "date": "2015-06-20",
    "content": "some text some text some text some text some text",
    "category": "category",
    "subcategory": [
      "some subcategory"
    ],
    "keywords": "keywords,keywords...",
    "id": "45654",
    "url": "article link"
  }];


  console.log(data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.date > a.date;
  }));
})();
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I just realized, i was over complicating it so much, and nothing has worked. Thank you so much :)