# load certain column of list in Flutter (it might be easy I think)

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter, and I have a list like this :

```
[{text: hello, date: 2020-09-11}, {text: hi, date: 2020-09-12},{text: why, date: 2020-09-11},
{text: how, date: 2020-09-10},{text: when, date: 2020-09-11},{text:flutter, date: 2020-09-12}]
```

I'd like to pick this from a table with a lot of overlapping elements.
`[2020-09-10, 2020-09-11, 2020-09-12]`

How can I sort the table like above? I don't know how to load certain column of list. ex) date

[image]

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453923/how-to-sort-json-by-date-newest-to-oldest

Comment: @evan but I want only date table not sort whole one. How can I call it?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807999/how-to-sort-json-data-in-flutter

Comment: @evan Isn't it possible to use this method `toSet().toList`? I need an example code. thx.

Comment: I am not sure about it

Comment: @evan I don't get it even after reading your linked page. I think there's misunderstanding, so added the image. How can I load only the date table? I tried `list.date, list[date]` but it didn't work.